# Updated Visual Studio, now wxWidgets complains about unresolved symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, wxwidgets

Problem description:

1. I have a Visual Studio 2012 C++ project which uses wxWidgets. It compiles and links perfectly.
2. For reasons we won't go into, I now need to make this work with Visual Studio 2015.
3. Having twiddled the settings and got all the code to compile, it now refuses to link because all the libraries it uses are compiled for VS 2012. OK...
4. I replaced all the libraries with ones compiled for VS 2015. Everything works again... *except* wxWidgets.

I have now spent *multiple days* fruitlessly trying to force wxWidgets to work. It just won't do it.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Looking at the instructions at https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/, it appears I'm supposed to download and unpack two files:

  - `wxWidgets-3.1.1-headers.7z` (which contains an `include` folder)
  - `wxMSW-3.1.1_vc140_Dev.7z` (which contains a `lib` folder).
- I deleted the old wxWidgets stuff, and unpacked these two new zips.
- Hundreds of preprocessor errors saying it can't find some include file. It looks like the old directory structure had `...\lib\vc_lib\...` rather than `..\lib\vc140_dll\...`, so I tried renaming the folder. Now everything compiles successfully.
- Next the linker complains that it can't find `wxbmsw28ud_core.lib` — which makes sense, considering I just deleted it. I changed all the filenames to be `*31` rather than `*28`, and no more file-not-found errors.
- Now I have hundreds of LNK2001 errors. For example:

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: static struct wxEventTable const wxDialogBase::sm_eventTable" (?sm_eventTable@wxDialogBase@@1UwxEventTable@@B)

I don't understand this though. If I run `DumpBin.exe` against `wxmsw31ud_core.lib`, it dumps out several megabytes of text, including:

```
5146A2 __imp_?sm_eventTable@wxDialogBase@@1UwxEventTable@@B
```

and also

```
29C0 __imp_?sm_eventTable@wxDialogBase@@1UwxEventTable@@B
```

and also

```
Version      : 0
Machine      : 14C (x86)
TimeDateStamp: 5A8A0543 Sun Feb 18 22:59:15 2018
SizeOfData   : 00000049
DLL name     : wxmsw311ud_core_vc140.dll
Symbol name  : ?sm_eventTable@wxDialogBase@@1UwxEventTable@@B (protected: static struct wxEventTable const wxDialogBase::sm_eventTable)
Type         : data
Name type    : name
Hint         : 14306
Name         : ?sm_eventTable@wxDialogBase@@1UwxEventTable@@B
```

In other words, *the exact symbol that VS says it can't find!*

So if the symbol is *in* the `.lib` file and I can *see it* there, why is VS complaining that it's not in the `.lib` file?

Just to be 100% certain, I made a table of every single symbol that VS claims it can't find and which `.lib` file it's actually in:

```
LNK2001 ?sm_eventTable@wxDialogBase@@1UwxEventTable@@B                wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxTheAssertHandler@@3P6AXABVwxString@@H000@ZA                wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?wxTrapInAssert@@3_NA                                         wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?wxConvLibcPtr@@3PAVwxMBConv@@A                               wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?wxEmptyString@@3PB_WB                                        wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?npos@wxString@@2IB                                           wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?sm_first@wxClassInfo@@0PAV1@A                                wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?wxNullBitmap@@3VwxBitmap@@A                                  wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxNullIcon@@3VwxIcon@@A                                      wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxDefaultSize@@3VwxSize@@B                                   wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxDefaultPosition@@3VwxPoint@@B                              wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxEVT_NULL@@3HB                                              wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?wxEVT_BUTTON@@3V?$wxEventTypeTag@VwxCommandEvent@@@@B        wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxDefaultValidator@@3VwxValidator@@B                         wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxButtonNameStr@@3QBDB                                       wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?ms_classInfo@wxDialog@@2VwxClassInfo@@A                      wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxStaticTextNameStr@@3QBDB                                   wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxListCtrlNameStr@@3QBDB                                     wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxConvUTF8Ptr@@3PAVwxMBConvStrictUTF8@@A                     wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?ms_appInitFn@wxAppConsoleBase@@1P6APAVwxAppConsole@@XZA      wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?ms_appInstance@wxAppConsoleBase@@1PAVwxAppConsole@@A         wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?ms_idMainThread@wxThread@@0KA                                wxbase31ud.lib
LNK2001 ?wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW@@3V?$wxEventTypeTag@VwxCloseEvent@@@@B    wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxEVT_SIZING@@3V?$wxEventTypeTag@VwxSizeEvent@@@@B           wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxEVT_COMMAND_ENTER@@3V?$wxEventTypeTag@VwxCommandEvent@@@@B wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxTextCtrlNameStr@@3QBDB                                     wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK2001 ?wxGaugeNameStr@@3QBDB                                        wxmsw31ud_core.lib
LNK1120 28 unresolved externals
```

As you can see, every single symbol is listed in either `wxmsw31ud_core.lib` or `wxbase31ud.lib`, which are both configured in the project (along with several additional wxWidgets libraries as well).

I don't understand what the problem is. I don't get why it's complaining at me. But I need to make this work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right platform (x64 vs x86)?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yep. That was the first thing I did wrong. :-} (All the 64-bit versions have `_x64_` in the name.)

Comment: Can you check with depends.exe that your wxwidgets are also of the right platform?

Comment: This might be that the app has been compiled to expect to link with the wxWidgets DLLs but then actually linked with the static libs, or perhaps vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing compiled files from different VS versions will lead to errors ("not found" or "incompatible") in the linking stage. Also, mixing 32/64 versions will fail.

Delete (or move to a different dir) all of [old] wxWidgets stuff, specially the generated dirs and objects during a previous wxWidgets building.

Download current wxWidgets sources from [official page](https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/), or the Windows installer.

Build using the proper VS solution. Taken from `wxdir\docs\msw\install.txt`:

> Ready to use project files are provided for VC++ versions 7, 8, 9, 10,
>   11, 12, 14 and 15 (also known as MSVS 2003, 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012,
>   2013, 2015 and 2017 respectively).
>
> Simply open wx_vcN.sln (for N=7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, or 15) file,
>   select the appropriate configuration (Debug or Release, static or DLL)
>   and build the solution. Notice that when building a DLL configuration,
>   you may need to perform the build several times because the projects
>   are not always built in the correct order, and this may result in link
>   errors. Simply do the build again, up to 3 times, to fix this.

So, simply open `wx_vc14.sln` and build your solution. It seems you want `static` library, so wx gets embedded into your app; if not, select the DLL solution.

Notice that in that wxWidgets download page you can directly get the headers and the static ("Development") or dynamic ("Release DLL") already compiled files, so as to avoid wxWidgets compilation itself.

Comment: The "static already compiled files" are exactly what I'm trying to use. For some reason, it's not working. (I'd like to avoid spending 6 months working out how to build wxWidgets from source if possible.)

Comment: Be sure not to have old versions around. "6 months" become "6 minutes" if you follow the `wx_vc14.sln` way.

Answer (score 0):

Your link error is due to the linker looking for the function in a static library, while you're linking with DLL import libraries. IOW when you write

> In other words, the exact symbol that VS says it can't find!

it is just wrong because there is clearly a difference: one symbol has the `__imp__` prefix and the other one doesn't.

Either rebuild your application with `WXUSINDLL` defined or link with static wx libraries.

And, honestly, all of us make mistakes and it may happen that you spend hours or even days on something that can be solved in minutes, but blaming your tools really doesn't help when the problem is not with them.

Comment: ...so you're saying the official binaries only offer the DLL versions and I'll have to build from source to get static binaries?

Comment: Yes, official binaries offer only DLL versions. I do believe that this is really rather clearly spelt out on the downloads page which speaks about "wxMSW DLLs", why is it a surprise?

Comment: Several places in the documentation seem to claim that *static* linking is the default...

Answer (score 0):

On top of a great help from Vadim and Ripi2, I think you are also trying to upgrade wxWidgets from version 2.8 to 3.0. This is in itself a huge task and you should consider do one properly then the other.

I'd start with the building 2.8 source statically with the compiler at hand and then try to ujpgrade the version of wxWidgets very carefully.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave up and attempted to build wxWidgets from source.

It took many, *many* attempts, but eventually I was able to compile wxWidgets in such a way that my application now builds successfully. It seems you have to check that all the hundreds of thousands of compilation settings in VS are identical to the target application. No, it doesn't seem to be possible to automate that.

(Having said all that, compared to how nightmarishly difficult it usually is to build anything C-related from source, this was comparatively easy...)